# Why does $SHELL point to /bin/bash if running zsh inside bash?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, zsh

If I run `zsh` inside `bash` (on macOS Sierra), why does `$SHELL` still point to `/bin/bash`, rather then `/bin/zsh`?

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ zsh
% echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$SHELL` should point to your *login* shell, not current shell. As in, `grep $USER /etc/passwd` - it shows you your login shell which is probably /bin/bash.

You need to change shell with `chsh` to make the change permanent.